# Consulta Select Mysql

Tags: mysql, javafx

Buenos dias a todos antes que nada!

Hoy tengo una duda como todos los dias.

[image: Bueno tengo esta tabla:]

tengo esta tabla en JavaFX como ven tengo 2 columnas Placa y Km Sobrepasado
Entonces lo que necesito hacer aqui es cargar los datos Placa y KmSobrepoasado desde mu tabla control en mysql lo que sucede es que el campo Km Sobrepasado es una suma de todos los Kilometrajes que se han introducido en la columna kmrecoaux:
esta es la columna. Para obtener eso utlizo sum(kmrecoaux) as SumKmTotal

[image: columna]

aqui les muestro la consulta que intente hacer pero me da error:

```
SELECT placa, kmrecoaux FROM control where sum(kmrecoaux) >= 5000
```

Ok ahora diran Pero que quieres hacer con esos datos y esa tabla!
Respuesta: Necesito mostrar todas las placas de los vehiculos que la suma de su kmrecoaux sea mayor o igual a 5000. lo que quiere decir que necesita mantenimiento.
Pero como la suma es una columna que se crea por un "as" no se como realizar la consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql es el único motor de bases de datos relacionales (que conozco) que permite usar funciones de agregación junto con otras columnas, y no tener un `GROUP BY` explícito. Pero lo recomendable es que uses SQL estándar, y no dependas de esas malas prácticas.

Dicho esto, cuando quieres hacer limitar el valor de una función de agregación (como en este caso, de la suma de kilómetros), lo que se debe usar es `HAVING` (después del `GROUP BY`).

De esta forma, la consulta que necesitas es la siguiente:

```
SELECT placa, SUM(kmrecoaux) as Km_Sobrepasado
FROM control
GROUP BY placa
HAVING SUM(kmrecoaux) >= 5000
;
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Probando!